# MSMQ 3.0 / 4.0 download

Tags: download, msmq

I need to use messaging using MSMQ in a project at work and my developement environment (Win XP SP3) came with MSMQ 2.0 only.  Need some features of MSMQ 3.0  (like poison queues) and am having a hard time finding the installable for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please ignore my question.  I was mistaken as I found that MSMQ 3.0 was installed on my envioronment.  From the link below

https://blogs.msdn.com/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/05/14/how-to-tell-if-msmq-is-installed.aspx

"Query the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\CurrentBuild registry value

5.0.xxx is MSMQ 2.0 (Windows 2000)
5.1.xxx is MSMQ 3.0 (Windows XP)
5.2.xxx is MSMQ 3.0 (Windows 2003)
6.xxxxx is MSMQ 4.0 (Windows Vista and 2008)
"

Answer (score 2):

To install Microsoft Message Queuing
1.       Log on as a member of the Administrators group to the server that will be running the Archiving and CDR Server.
2.       Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Add or Remove Programs.
3.       Click Add/Remove Windows Components, click Application Server, and then click Details.
4.       Select the Message Queuing check box, click OK, and then click Next.
5.       Accept the defaults in the wizard to complete the installation.